# PyOpenGL - update triangles array when some of the scene elements need to disappear

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, rendering, pyopengl

I have a scene that I need to render quickly. So I successfully generate the vertices of the triangles as numpy, upload to GPU and render it very fast. So far so good.

The problem starts when some of the elements in the scene need to disappear from the scene. What I do is traverse the entire array and filter out the vertices the scene elements that no longer need to be drawn, upload it again to GPU and then render it. This obviously takes a few seconds which is unacceptable. I'm looking for a quick way to modify the array and redraw the scene.

This a simplified version of the code I use: (Would also appreciate any comments about the code itself)

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import numpy as np
import ctypes

vertex_dtype = [("position", np.float32, 3), ("color", np.float32, 4)]
vertex_array_object = None
vertex_buffer = None
shader_program = .......

def upload_to_gpu(vertices_np):
    global vertex_array_object, vertex_buffer
    if vertex_array_object is None:
        vertex_array_object = glGenVertexArrays(1)
    if vertex_buffer is None:
        vertex_buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_np.nbytes, vertices_np, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    stride = vertices_np.strides[0]
    offset = ctypes.c_void_p(0)
    position_location = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, 'a_position')
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(position_location)
    glVertexAttribPointer(position_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)

    offset = ctypes.c_void_p(vertices_np.dtype["position"].itemsize)
    color_location = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program, "a_color")
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(color_location)
    glVertexAttribPointer(color_location, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)

    glBindVertexArray(0)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

def create_np_array(all_vertices):
    vertices_np = np.zeros(len(all_vertices), dtype=vertex_dtype)
    cur_idx = 0
    for vertex in all_vertices:        
        if ....should_ignore_triangle....:
            continue
        vertices_np[cur_idx]["position"] = [vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2]]
        vertices_np[cur_idx]["color"] = ......
        cur_idx += 1

    vertices_np = vertices_np[:cur_idx]
    return vertices_np

def draw_scene(vertices_np):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glUseProgram(shader_program)
    # Set view and projection matrix    
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices_np.shape[0])

def main():
    all_vertices = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], ......]   # long list of ~million vertices
    vertices_np = create_np_array(all_vertices)
    upload_to_gpu(vertices_np)

    # Now we are ready to start rendering
    draw_scene(vertices_np) # works fine

    # Now something changes and we need to regenerate the vertices_np and upload it again
    vertices_np = create_np_array(all_vertices)   # <-- THIS TAKES TOO MUCH TIME
    upload_to_gpu(vertices_np)
    draw_scene(vertices_np) # works fine
```

Comment: Note, [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) creates and initializes a data store on the GPU this is an expensive operation. [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) would only update a subset of the data. If you know the indices of the vertices which you want to omit, why don't you omit them when drawing. Use 2 draw calls or [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) for drawing a subset of the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to omit vertices, but you don't want to add new ones, then I recommend just to draw the subset of vertices you want. Don't change any data on the GPU or recreate any vertex array.

Create an array of tuples, which contains the index ranges of the vertices, to be drawn. For this find the first vertex which has to be omitted and append a "range" tuple to the tuple list. Find the next vertex which should be drawn and repeat the process till the end of the array:

```
def draw_np_array(all_vertices):

    idx_list = []
    cur_start_idx = 0
    cur_end_idx = 0
    for vertex in all_vertices:

        if ....should_ignore_triangle....:
            if cur_end_idx > cur_start_idx:
                idx_list.append( (cur_start_idx, cur_end_idx) );
            cur_end_idx += 1
            cur_start_idx = cur_end_idx
            continue

        cur_end_idx += 1

    if cur_end_idx > cur_start_idx:
        idx_list.append( (cur_start_idx, cur_end_idx) );

    return idx_list
```

Draw the scene with an "intelligent" draw call:

```
def draw_scene(idx_list):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glUseProgram(shader_program)
    # Set view and projection matrix
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)

    for idx_range in idx_list:
        start = idx_range[0]
        count = idx_range[1]-idx_range[0]
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, start, count)
```

You can further improve this by using [`glMultiDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawArrays.xhtml), which can draw multiple ranges of an array by one draw call, instead of drawing the arrays in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't quite understand your code. What do you mean by "filter out the vertices"? Like deleting all the triangles that include a certain vertex? And do you have an index buffer beforehand or you generate it procedurally?

Anyway, you can just set an additional layout with flag (`true`/`false` or `0` / `1`) for each vertex. And in the fragment shader just check if this variable (interpolated or not) is greater than 0 or not. If it's greater - you draw the pixel. If it's not - you [`discard`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/discard.php) it. It's probably the easiest way and could be implemented like in a few minutes.